How to sync two similar lists/waveforms with differently populated data in python?
I have two lists of sizes L1 - 22400(865*26) and L2 - 79000 with measurements of some environmental data. Data of both the lists are measured simultaneously. The L2 is a continuous measurement for 79000 samples whereas L1 is a measurement with some intervals between them - To be exact 26 separate measurements of 865 samples each. The interval between these measurements are not constant since it depends on a certain hardware constraint. So, there are these 26 chunks of 865 samples in L2 which are similar(not same) to each L1 sample and I need to find these chunks and sync them. Let me know if there is any library to work with such waveform or such data or if there is any clever algorithms related to this.
P.S - I was supposed to measure the data with time and sync them accordingly but messed up. I have also done some estimations about the hardware delay and tried to sync it up accordingly but since the hardware delay is variable, there are left shifts in some areas and right shifts in some areas of the waveform.
Let me know if you need any other information regarding this.
